# Adding data to a most_common() list?

Tags: python, list, counter

After running Python's `most_common()` function  on a list of domain names, it is giving me a result like this:

```
[('gmail.com', 221571), ('yahoo.com', 71635), ('hotmail.com', 70890)]
```

I have many other lists with domain names. I need to take the results from most_common() and add the items from a list of domain names to the results. My initial thought to solve this problem was to combine all lists into one, then run `most_common()`, but I am working with an extremely large data set that is too big to do this. After searching, I was unable to find a way to do this.

Comment: Why not count the number of occurrences?

Comment: Are you saying that the data set is too large to hold in memory, or that it's large enough that a sort would take too long?

Comment: what is `most_common`, and you just want to count number of distinct `.com`'s?

Comment: If I store all the domain names from all the files I have, it would be way too large to hold in memory. What I have so far is: 1. Iterate over a file and pull the 1000 most common domain names. 2. Store the results in a binary file. 3. Iterate over the next list and pull the 1000 most common from that file. 4. Access the binary file and combine the most common results (the issue). 5. Repeat until all files have been analyzed –

Comment: most_common() returns a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least.

Comment: So this cumulative binary file is too large to process by reading it all into memory at once?

Comment: @aws_apprentice: I believe the OP is referring to the [`collections.Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method (esp given that the question is tagged "counter").

Comment: @Tobias Wilfert: Because just doing that also requires keeping track of a separate count for each domain name, something which would logically be done via a dictionary in Python -- and is exactly what the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dictionary subclass does.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to collections.Counter.most_common()

Comment: I think you should check out Pyspark with a couple cheap machines or cloud based VMs if it's really that much data

Comment: Have you had a look at `pandas`? If I remember, it was able to efficiently handle a CSV file of 2-3 GB size. You can do various kinds of manipulation easily once you parse a table.